# Read-only property on BindProperty object is being called before OnPost()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-5

I have a Razor Pages application. And my page model includes the following.

```
[BindProperty]
public TripSearchModel Search { get; set; }
```

When the page is posted, the `Search` object is correctly populated.

However, my `TripSearchModel` also includes a read-only property `IsEmpty`:

```
public class TripSearchModel
{

    // Bound properties here...

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            // Validate data and return true if nothing set
        }
    }
}
```

When the page is posted, the getter for the `IsEmpty` property is called. This all happens before the `OnPost()` handler is called.

Here is the stack trace:

```
TTRailtrax.dll!TTRailtrax.ViewModels.TripSearchModel.IsEmpty.get() Line 81  C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyHelper.CallNullSafePropertyGetter<TTRailtrax.ViewModels.TripSearchModel, bool>(System.Func<TTRailtrax.ViewModels.TripSearchModel, bool> getter, object target)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.DefaultComplexObjectValidationStrategy.Enumerator.MoveNext.AnonymousMethod__1()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationEntry.Model.get()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitChildren(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.IValidationStrategy strategy)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitComplexType(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.IValidationStrategy defaultStrategy)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitImplementation(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadata metadata, ref string key, object model)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadata metadata, string key, object model)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Validate(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadata metadata, string key, object model, bool alwaysValidateAtTopLevel, object container)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ObjectModelValidator.Validate(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext actionContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationStateDictionary validationState, string prefix, object model, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadata metadata, object container)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.EnforceBindRequiredAndValidate(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ObjectModelValidator baseObjectValidator, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext actionContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.ParameterDescriptor parameter, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadata metadata, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBindingResult modelBindingResult, object container)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext actionContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IModelBinder modelBinder, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IValueProvider valueProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.ParameterDescriptor parameter, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadata metadata, object value, object container)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageBinderFactory.CreatePropertyBinder.__Bind|0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageContext pageContext, object instance)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.BindArgumentsCoreAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.BindArgumentsAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointFactory.CreateRequestDelegate.AnonymousMethod__0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.ProcessRequestAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>.ProcessRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.HandleRequest()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.Execute()
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Does anyone know why a read-only property on my `[BindProperty]` object would be called by Razor Pages? Or how I can stop this (it is a big method and I don't want it running unnecessarily)?

Comment: Maybe you can log the stack trace inside that property getter to find it out?

Comment: @Evk: The stack shows the getter is called from `[External Code]`. So it's being called by the framework. I just don't know why.

Comment: You can disable "just my code" in debugger settings to see the actual stack trace, I think.

Comment: @Evk: Then it says it was called by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyHelper.CallNullSafePropertyGetter<TTRailtrax.ViewModels.TripSearchModel, bool>(System.Func<TTRailtrax.ViewModels.TripSearchModel, bool> getter, object target)`. Don't think that helps.

Comment: Well you can now at least see it's caused by asp.net model validation. What happens if you apply [ValidateNever] attribute to this property?

Comment: @Evk: Well, I knew it was caused by model validation. What didn't make sense is why the validation would be calling the getter of a read-only property. But `[ValidateNever]` does in fact prevent it from happening. Thanks for that.

Comment: Maybe I'm too amateur at Razor stuff, but why is validation hitting a property of any kind that doesn't have any sort of validation rules defined for it? What could it possible be validating against?

Comment: @Logarr: That's my question. So I'm asking Microsoft [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37596).